# How to shrink arrow labels in xymatrix?

Tags: xy-pic

I know how to shrink a diagram changing the column or row spacing, but I don't know to do it for the arrow labels. I can shrink an entry by using the standard font size changing commands, like \small, \scriptstyle, etc. However this doesn't work for arrow labels. For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}% a minimal example

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\xyoption{pdf}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \xymatrix{
    \scriptstyle{X}\ar[d]^{F_0}_{\scriptstyle{F_0}}\\
    Y
    }
  \]
\end{document}
```

works for the entry X but not for the arrow label. Is there a way to shrink arrow labels in xymatrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to box the `\xymatrix` and to choose the font size in the box.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}% a minimal example
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\mbox{\xymatrix{ X\ar[d]^{F_0}_{F_0}\\ Y }}
\quad
\mbox{\small
  \xymatrix{ X\ar[d]^{F_0}_{F_0}\\ Y }%
}
\quad
\mbox{\footnotesize
  \xymatrix{ X\ar[d]^{F_0}_{F_0}\\ Y }%
}
\quad
\mbox{\scriptsize
  \xymatrix{ X\ar[d]^{F_0}_{F_0}\\ Y }%
}
\quad
\mbox{\tiny
  \xymatrix{ X\ar[d]^{F_0}_{F_0}\\ Y }%
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've been told that \scriptscriptstyle would work for arrow labels, if one wants to shrink arrow labels only, and it does. I tried \tiny, but it doesn't. I don't know why.